# Where is the Pesach seder discussed in the Mishna?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, mishna

I heard a podcast that discussed the differences between the Pesach Seder as described in the Mishna and what we do today. But I couldn't catch the name/number of the relevant mishnaot. What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tenth (final) chapter of Pesachim  deals with Seder practices such as the Mishnaic version of Mah Nishtana.

Comment: It also gives the origin for the expression, "[Raise the roof!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=raise+the+roof)"